# Building Business Software using Qt

Tags: qt

I want to build a business software such as : a traveller management software . My software have some requirements:

+) Can run on PC and Mobile
+) Data on the cloud

I intend to build UI by Qml . I heard about the Qt cloud service but don’t know clearly

Is it feasible to build such a software using Qt Quick and Qt cloud service ? The pros and cons of building business software on cloud using Qt compare to other solutions ( .Net or ………)

Could you please clarify for me ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is a cross platform library for Graphics and other general purposes.

Designing a backend for managing a shared database has been done millions of times and is possible with lots of different technologies.

QML is a scripting layer for making easy to iterate frontends for Qt.  Often heavy tasks need to be connected back to C++, but QML and Qt Quick are maturing quickly.  They also leverage the scenegraph usage of graphics cards really well.

I'm not sure what you think of python, but I ran across this project a while back and I think it is relevant:

http://www.python-camelot.com/

Websockets and other technologies are leveraged by Qt Enginio project:

http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/category/enginio/

### Connecting to a Database

Basically you want to keep some kind of excel spreadsheet like object for any of your clients to connect to.

If you just put up a MySQL database up there, and left it open for any computer to remotely access, you are likely to get hacked.  Most people put some layer between the database and the world wide web with better security.

A simple example would be a MySQL database with a php frontend.  Php accepts requests and turns them into database queries.  The database is protected because it can only be accessed by the php code running on the server, and you can put a lot of security in front of that php code.

### RESTful Services

So you could have a full blown website where you log in and see a view of the database, but maybe you just need to get a subset of information.  You can make a JSON or XML view into the database.

CRUD refers to Create, Read, Update, Delete.  These common commands are typical actions on database rows/entries.  JSON formalizes the requests and responses in a common way.

### How to use a RESTful Service from a Client program

Qt can do this, and so can a lot of other languages, but Qt makes it easier to do the cross platform drawing of the table or buttons or other elements.

### Qt Enginino Examples

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/enginio-qml-types-and-examples.html

Websockets and other technologies are leveraged by Qt Enginio project:

http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/category/enginio/

### QNetworkAccessManager

After you have a basic knowledge of network ports, addresses, replies and requests, the simplicity of QNetworkAccessManager and its supporting classes make life very easy.  The examples may stretch you a bit as you are learning it, but it is awesome.

### Other Options

There are all sorts of options out there for a complete solution.  Some of what you may ask yourself is what technology is recommended by your engineers on your project.  What is scalable?  What does my hosting service support?  Should I find a new hosting service that can support the kind of tables I am using?  Should I use NoSQL? Etc.

Looking at Qt is a great idea.  It is powerful.  It has been up to the task for all sorts of things.

Databases are very doable, and planning how you are going to do it is very helpful.

Hopefully my ramblings are helpful.  Good luck.

Hope that helps.